# how can I get details of a second leg call with twilio?

Tags: ruby, sinatra, twilio

I want to get the call details, from a second leg call, and insert them into my database.

Here is the scenario: an inbound call to a toll-free number is routed to second phone. So there are 2 legs, 1) the inbound call to the toll-free number and then 2) connection to the second number.

The code for getting the call details for the FIRST leg is:

```
get '/hangup' do
user_key = numbers.where(:number => params["To"]).join(:credentials, :user_id => :user_id).get(:user_key)
user_token = numbers.where(:number => params["To"]).join(:credentials, :user_id => :user_id).get(:user_token)
call_sid = params["CallSid"]
call_parent_sid = ["ParentCallSid"]
@sub_account_client = Twilio::REST::Client.new(user_key, user_token)
@subaccount = @sub_account_client.account 
call = @subaccount.calls.get(call_sid)
    call_sid = call.sid,
    call_parent_sid =  call.parent_call_sid,
    phone_number_id =  call.phone_number_sid,
    call_from = call.from,
    call_to =  call.to,
    call_start =  call.start_time,
    call_end =  call.end_time,
    call_duration =  call.duration,
    charged_duration = ((call_duration.to_f)/60).ceil
    call_price =  call.price
    call_charged_price = (charged_duration * 0.07)
call_logs.insert(:call_sid => call_sid, :call_parent_sid => call_parent_sid, :phone_number_id => phone_number_id, :call_from => call_from, :call_to => call_to, :call_start => call_start, :call_end => call_end, :call_duration => call_duration, :charged_duration => charged_duration, :call_price => call_price, :call_charged_price => call_charged_price)
end
```

This works after hangup and the status_callback_url is '/hangup'. But how can I get the same details for the second leg of the call. I have tried as follows:

```
get '/receive' do
destination_number = numbers.where(:number => params["To"]).join(:users, :id => :user_id).get(:primary_number)
user_id = numbers.where(:number => params["To"]).join(:users, :id => :user_id).get(:id)
greeting_url = voicemail.where(:user_id => user_id).get(:voicemail_play_url)
       resp = Twilio::TwiML::Response.new do |r|
        r.Dial destination_number, :status_callback => '/hangup_second_leg', :status_callback_method => 'GET'
```

etc..

This effectively attempts to create a second status_callback_url which, needless to say, did not work.

So, how can I get the details of the second (or even third) leg of a call and bung it into my DB?

Twilio evangelist .....

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Twilio developer evangelist at your service!

I just ran a quick test and the parameters you get back from the hangup callback should include a "CallSid" and a "DialedCallSid" which are the two legs of your call. You can get hold of the data via normal calls to the REST api:

```
get '/hangup' do
  call_sid = params["CallSid"]
  dialed_call_sid = params["DialedCallSid"]
  @sub_account_client = Twilio::REST::Client.new(user_key, user_token)
  @subaccount = @sub_account_client.account 
  inbound = @subaccount.calls.get(call_sid)
  outbound = @subaccount.calls.get(dialed_call_sid)
  # Update calls in database
end
```

Alternatively, the inbound call is the parent of all the other calls that take part within the context of the call. So you can get the details on all the child calls with the following api calls:

```
@subaccount.calls.list parent_call_sid: params["CallSid"]
# => [<Twilio::REST::Call>, ...]
```

Also, if you are getting a `ParentCallSid` parameter in your hangup, then you can use the above code to look up the parent call and child calls from that too.

Hope this helps, let me know if there's anything else I can help with.

Comment: thank you gracious TDE. Sorry for slow reply (I am in Japan), we have a problem. parentcallsid is empty and here is what I get in my terminal: "GET /hangup?AccountSid=ACac2a5b815cdcd688200c30dd3a7de092&CallStatus=completed&ToZip=&ToCity=&ToState=&Called=%2B448008085510&To=%2B448008085510&CallDuration=15&ToCountry=GB&CalledZip=&Direction=inbound&ApiVersion=2010-04-01&Caller=%2B1000000000&CalledCity=&CalledCountry=GB&Duration=1&CallSid=CAeaf9b93be24f664be078e934a6443617&CalledState=&From=%2B1000000000 HTTP/1.1" 12 - 2.2821
as you can see no parentcallsid param. I am stuck.

Comment: I should add for full explanation that teh callnback_url is set as follows: :status_callback => "http://6c93ce61.ngrok.com/hangup", :status_callback_method => 'GET' and here is what I get when I query with a known call_sid: {"sid":"CAeaf9b93be24f664be078e934a6443617","parent":null,"phone_number_id":"PNa337ddde1fe16df6757b764d8b7be5f9","date":"Thu, 06 Nov 2014 08:13:31 +0000","from":"+1000000000","to":"+448008085510","start":"Thu, 06 Nov 2014 08:13:33 +0000","end":"Thu, 06 Nov 2014 08:13:48 +0000","price":"-0.05750","duration":"15"} still no parent even though the call was redirected.

Comment: Ah, so in this case you are not getting a ParentCallSid or a DialedCallSid in the callback. I can't tell you why that is, but what I can tell you is that your call _is_ the parent call. So, you can look up the child calls by the call sid you have there. Try calling `@subaccount.calls.list :parent_call_sid => 'CAeaf9b93be24f664be078e934a6443617'`. You should find the child call in there.

Comment: I am stuck with this and something else now. So please can we resume this dialog later? I need to experiment more ...

Comment: Sure, or feel free to reach out to me on email at philnash@twilio.com

Comment: thanks Phil, I will. I went to a twilio training day in May in London - it was very interesting.